# How can i use an JavaScript(AJAX) variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I want to use my var 'resp' in php, so i can add the JSON request info in my database.
this is the code i ame using now:

```
 $.ajax({ 
            url: 'https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.1/game/by-summoner/20986461/recent?api_key=' <?php echo rawurlencode($key); ?>,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: false,
            error: function(){},
            success: function(resp){
            <?php
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO Game VALUES('', '1', 'Blue', '1', 'WIN')");
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO Game VALUES('1', '2', 'Red', '1', 'Lose')");
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO Game VALUES('1', '3', 'Green', '1', 'Draw')");
            ?>
            }
        });
```

so instead of:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Game VALUES('1', '2', 'Red', '1', 'Lose')");
```

i want this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Game VALUES(resp.id, resp.value, resp.team, resp.unit, resp.status)");
```

i know that doesnt work, and i tried searching online for answer but couldnt find anything.
TY in advance

Comment: You can't execute mysql_query directly from javascript.

Comment: You can't use javascript/jquery variable in php, vice-versa is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you'll have to do is, on success, make another AJAX call to a PHP script that just runs the mysql_query's.  And you could really just use something like [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to do that instead of the full $.ajax method.  Or maybe have a PHP script do the whole thing… grabbing that URL of JSON content etc.

Comment: I cant really figure it out. can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Which would you rather do?  Have one PHP script do everything with one AJAX call, or have two AJAX calls… one to get the JSON data, and a second to your mysql PHP script?

Comment: One php would be better i think.

Comment: So do you know how to get get the JSON into your PHP with file_get_contents and json_decode?

Comment: I fixed already, i use the file_get_contents and send it to my database using forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do that, since JavaScript runs on the client-side and PHP gets executed on the server-side.

You would need to execute the JavaScript first and then send the result to the server via a FORM or AJAX call.